# is there any way to use code completion for FMS .asc files on FDT 5+?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, flash, flash-media-server, fdt

I knew it was possible on an old verision of Flash Builder, but would be great to have this on FDT

Answer (score 0):

Currently FDT does not support .ASC files.